# SQL Join to get data from either tables (multiple tables)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: person, sav_account and cur_account. **I am trying to write a query that would select the amount, for all persons, from either table**. I am not trying to add the values if amount is found in both tables.

The Schema is as follows:

```
Person
-------
ID      |NAME       |AGE
1       |ICHIGO     |25
2       |NAMI       |21
3       |LUFFY      |18

SAV_ACCOUNT
-----------

ID      |AMOUNT
1       |10000
3       |20


CUR_ACCOUNT
-----------

ID      |AMOUNT
2       |100000000
```

I wrote this query but it gives me an empty set

```
select * from person p 
    inner join sav_account sa on (p.id = sa.id)
    inner join cur_account ca on (p.id = ca.id)
```

With this query, I am not getting the correct data.

```
select * from person p, sav_account sa, cur_account ca 
where p.id = sa.id OR p.id = ca.id
```

I am trying to get the final data like this:

```
ID      |NAME       |AGE        |AMOUNT
1       |ICHIGO     |25         |10000
3       |LUFFY      |18         |20 
2       |NAMI       |21         |1000000
```

Please advice.

Comment: is there are possibility that a person has amount in both tables? if that's the case, what value will you get?

Comment: Look into left join and coalesce. Or union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, a.Age,
        COALESCE(b.Amount, c.Amount, 0) Amount
FROM    Person a
        LEFT JOIN Sav_Account b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN Cur_Account c
            ON a.ID = c.ID
```

*Followup Question: Is there are possibility that a person has amount in both tables? if that's the case, what value will you get?*

Comment: If data is present in both tables, either will be ok.

Comment: well try the query above, it takes the amount from `savings` first then if it does not exist then on `current`, otherwise `0` will be displayed.